# How to Get disable dropdown value from yii form

Tags: yii, yii2

Iam having

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'parentid')
                                ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'firstName'), 
                                    ['prompt'=>'-Select a Parent-'])
                                 ?>
```

When i submit the form,iam getting parentid value is empty.

I have disable the dropdown by jquery

```
$("#register-parentid").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

Im getting empty value and i have referred, as said , we cannot get the value from disable field. Then how can i get the values from disable.

Iam using same form for two functions. One for disable field and another one for non disable .

Answer (score 0):

I tried lot. but i didn't get the solutions for this one.

Finally, I have playing with jquery.
When i submit the form, i have disabling the readonly field

```
$('button[type=submit]').on('click', function (event, attribute) {
       $("#register-parentid").prop("disabled", false);
    });
```